# Trouble connecting to the internet in windows (dual boot ubuntu)

Tags: networking, dual-boot, internet

I'm having an original `Windows 8.1` dual booted with `Ubuntu 15.04`. My `ISP` has given me IP address and other settings to access the internet through LAN cable. I've same setting in both windows and ubuntu. But in windows I'm unable to access the internet, at the same time when i log in in ubuntu it works fine. Can anybody tell me how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wandering around settings, I found that in windows I'd `Proxy`. After disabling it, problem got resolved.